# trigger('click') vs trigger('click')[0]

Tags: jquery

I am unable to differentiate between `trigger('click')` vs `trigger('click')[0]`, is there any difference between them?

Comment: Where did you see any use of `trigger('click')[0]`???

Answer (score 5):

`trigger('click')` calls the `trigger` method with the `'click'` parameter.

`trigger('click')[0]` calls the `trigger` method with the `'click'` parameter, and accesses the first element of whatever it's returning.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of methods in jQuery return the original jQuery collection to allow for easier chaining.

For instance

```
jQuery("body").trigger("click").css("background", "red"); 
// returns the jQuery collection.
```

If you use an index to access a jQuery collection, you'll get the corresponding DOM element, in my example, document.body.